# Invalid postback or callback argument when redirect on a SelectedIndexChanged from a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hi Im trying to redirect to another page on the gridView event: selectedIndexChanged. I dont want to set EnableEventValidation="false".

here is my code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!Page.IsPostBack)
   { 
       llenarGridViewClientes();
   }
}

protected void GridViewUsuarios_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["UsuarioHistoria"] = GridViewUsuarios.SelectedValue;
    Response.Redirect("Historia.aspx");
}
```

And page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBuscador" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ></asp:TextBox>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <asp:Button ID="btnBuscar" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary " Text="Buscar" OnClick="btnBuscar_Click"/>    
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="divGrid" style="overflow: auto; height: 430px" >
        <asp:GridView ID="GridViewUsuarios" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  AllowSorting="True" CellPadding="1" CssClass="table table-striped table-hover" GridLines="None" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" ForeColor="#333333" 
        DataKeyNames="id" AllowPaging="False"  Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridViewUsuarios_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" SelectText="Seleccionar" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" SortExpression="id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" Visible="false" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="nombre" HeaderText="Nombre" SortExpression="nombre" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="apellido" HeaderText="Apellido" SortExpression="apellido" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="telefono" HeaderText="Telefono" SortExpression="telefono" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="celular" HeaderText="Celular" SortExpression="celular" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="dni" HeaderText="DNI" SortExpression="dni" />
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

And here is the master page.

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:Timer ID="tmrRelojInterno" runat="server" OnTick="tmrRelojInterno_Tick1" Interval="1000"></asp:Timer>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tmrRelojInterno" EventName="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/logo.png" ImageAlign="Middle" Height="159px" with="934px" />
                <div style="display: inline-block">
                    <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbldia" runat="server" Font-Names=" arial" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="black" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblReloj" runat="server" Font-Names="arial" Font-Size="XX-Large"></asp:Label>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-inverse-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-inverse-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="Turnos.aspx">Turnos</a></li>

                <li><a href="ClienteHistoriaClinica.aspx">Historia Clinica</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Datos <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="Usuarios.aspx">Usuarios</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Profesiones.aspx">Profesiones</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Clientes.aspx">Clientes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Servicios.aspx">Servicios</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Consultar <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="TurnosEliminados.aspx">Turnos Eliminados</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <p class="navbar-text">

                    <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                        <LoggedInTemplate>
                            <asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="12" ForeColor="White" />

                            [
                            <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Cerrar sesión" LogoutPageUrl="~/" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="12" ForeColor="White" />
                            ]
                        </LoggedInTemplate>
                    </asp:LoginView>
                </p>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2 ">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="content3" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 ">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</form>
</body>
```

this is the stack trace

> [ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event
>   validation is enabled using  in
>   configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page. 
>   For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to
>   postback or callback events originate from the server control that
>   originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.]
>   System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent(String uniqueId,
>   String argument) +144
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox.LoadPostData(String postDataKey,
>   NameValueCollection postCollection) +126
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox.System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.LoadPostData(String
>   postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData,
>   Boolean fBeforeLoad) +303
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1960

Comment: Have you tried `Response.Redirect("Historia.aspx", true);`

Comment: yes , i did but it didnt work

Comment: It's possible that you have some bad HTML being generated from the data your binding with, or you might have multiple form tags. You'd have to post the HTML output to determine the cause.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I edited my question with more details. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `[YourFormName].Action = Request.RawURL;` to the page_load event of your master page, that resolved this issue for me.